# Rename selected values in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have simple query to select sales per region.

```
SELECT Sales, Region
FROM Sales_2019
GROUP BY Region
```

There are 2 regions in my table:

- Europe
- North America

Regions names needs to be changed to shortcuts:

- Europe -> EU
- North America -> NA

How can I rename it via query? I want query to show me EU instead of Europe and NA instead of North America.

Comment: you want to rename permanently in the table, or just change the output for the purpose of display in this particular select query? For the former, use an UPDATE query. For the latter, a SWITCH or nested IIF statement would probably make sense.

Comment: `case region when 'Europe' then 'EU' when 'North America' then 'NA' else '?' end`

Comment: @ADyson not in the table just output

Comment: @dnoeth in which in my query i need to put this?

Comment: In the Select instead of the column region.

Comment: @dnoeth I didn't think Access supported CASE statements?

Comment: @ADyson Of course, you're right, I didn't notice the Access tag

Answer (score 2):

`CASE` does not exist in ms-access, but you can use [the `SWITCH` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379?ocmsassetID=HA001228918&CorrelationId=8bad3e54-6e6f-45aa-8d42-67f7149ee2cb&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) :

```
SELECT 
    Sales,
    SWITCH( 
        Region="Europe", "EU",
        Region="North America", "NA"
    ) AS Region_name
FROM Sales_2019;
```

Comment: @matjan2 : ok thanks for your reply. Are you getting an error ? a wrong result ?

Comment: @matjan2 "not working" is not an error message or problem statement that we can help you with. Please be specific about what is going wrong when you try this query.

Answer (score 1):

**Using IIF**

```
select sum(sales) as sales_sum, IIF(region='Europe','EU', IIF(region='North America','NA',region))  as Region_name
from Sales_2019
group by region
```

**Using Switch**

```
SELECT 
    sum(Sales) as sales_sum,
    SWITCH( 
        Region="Europe", "EU",
        Region="North America", "NA"
    ) AS Region_name
FROM Sales_2019
group by region
```

Answer (score 0):

**It should be a simple solution**

Using Replace function :

> SELECT Sales, replace(replace(Region, 'Europe ', 'EU') ,'North
>   America', 'NA') as Region FROM Sales_2019 GROUP BY Region

Answer (score -1):

It should be simple case statement

```
select sum(sales) as sales_sum,
   case when Region='Europe' then 'EU'
        when Region='North America' then 'NA'
        else Region
    end as Region_name
FROM Sales_2019
GROUP BY Region;
```

Comment: what's with the `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: I didn't think Access supported CASE statements.

Comment: and @GMB,  I believe Matjan2 would want to use sum(sales) thus Group by being used?

Comment: Use `IIF` instead of `CASE` in MS Access.

Comment: "it works in SQL"..SQL is not a single language though... CASE works in some implementations of SQL...but not in the one used by MS Access. Your statement doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @ADyson.. I know there are various implementations of SQL.. the standard oracle sql does support the case statements.. if it doesn't support any other type of sql it doesn't mean that the code is wrong .. so better approach would be to provide alternate solutions instead of finding issues

Comment: @Rhythm there are plenty of alternate answers already which will do the job, I can't really add anything more useful than those. For clarity I'm well aware that standard SQL and other providers such as Oracle will support this syntax...but when the OP has very explicitly asked a question specifically about Access I can't begin to imagine why you'd knowingly provide them with an answer which isn't going to work on that platform, and is therefore useless to them for all practical purpose? Posting something which meets the standard is no good if it doesn't fit the relevant implementation as well.